# Local Umbraco Site Backoffice Unintentionally publishes to Live Production Site

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, umbraco

I'm fairly new at working with Umbraco and ASP.net. I'm working on getting an existing Umbraco site working locally but i'm having a few strange issues and I'm having some difficulty finding an answer.

When I load my backoffice the url is `http://localhost:52533/umbraco#/umbraco`. I just set up the local site and all of the content nodes from the site are there and they say they are in the cache, but not published.
When I click save and publish, the url for the content goes to my site `"www.mydomain.com/nodename"`, which is definitely not the behavior I expected.

When I try to load `http://localhost:52533/`, I get an error:

> Cannot create a Umbraco.Core.Security.UmbracoBackOfficeIdentity from System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity since the required claim http://umbraco.org/2015/02/identity/claims/backoffice/sessionid is missing.

If anyone can help me figure out what is going on here, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The first part is (most likely) because host names have been defined for the site.

Host names can be defined on any node in Umbraco, but inside Umbraco you navigate to the root content node inside Umbraco (the **parent** of "nodename" in your mydomain.com/nodename), right click it and select "Manage hostnames". If you just remove any defined host names the site should run fine on localhost.

I don't know if that corrects the second error as well :-s

Comment: In Addition to what Jannik said, i always add both host names one for the local and one for the live site so that when i update live or local with live both ends work as expected.